# Sphere mesh in Webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, mesh

I am trying to create a sphere by constructing a series of grids using latitude (phi) and longitude (theta). I have the calculations of the sphere down, however, I am not sure how to make theta range from 0 to 2pi and phi range from 0 to pi at each iteration.

```
function getSphereVertices()
{
    data = new Array(nRows);
    var r = 1;

    for(var i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
        var lon = 0; //find out how to calculate this (-PI to PI)
        data[i] = new Array(nColumns);            // -2.0 to 1.92
        for(var j=0; j<nColumns; j++) {
            var lat = 0; //find out how to calculate this (-PI/2 to PI/2)
            var x = r * Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(lon);
            var y = r * Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(lon);
            var z = r * Math.cos(lat);


            pointsArray.push(vec4(x, y, z, 1.0));   
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the a linear value representing the longitude in the range [0, 1]:

```
var lon = i/nRows;
```

Map this value form the range [0, 1] to [-PI, PI]:

```
lon = (lon*2.0-1.0) * Math.PI;
```

Do similar for the latitude, but map from [0, 1] to [-PI/2, PI/2]:

```
var lat = j/nColumns;
lat = (lat*2.0-1.0) * Math.PI/2;
```